# what pattern to use for a concurrent forum server?

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency

I need to write a message board application and the server should be able to service several clients simultaneously. At the moment my default choice is to use the reactor pattern (since it's the only one i learnt and know) but i was wondering if there are other/better options.

Also, suggestions of open source implementations of suitable patterns will be welcome.

Just to be clear, I am not asking about an http server. At the moment the application has nothing to do with http.
The question is strictly about design patterns.

Thank you.

Comment: To a person whose only tool is a hammer, everything is a nail.

Comment: Are you able to use an application server / servlet container ( eg tomcat / jetty ) to provide the infrastructure - it means you'll be able to concentrate on the acquisition and presentation of the messages without having to worry about writing the server to process the incoming requests

Comment: This is an educational assignment. At the moment i need to implement the server.

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, I assume you guys are just using sockets and sending messages back and forth over the sockets?

Comment: "If you need design patterns change your language" ;) It was Norvig. Your problem is super easy in Erlang (erlang.org). It can also communicate with Java easily..

Comment: Will clients all post to one board?  Or will it be more like IM.  Essentially will clients subscribe to a board that they are posting to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find much info about other design patters for a server except proactor but i'm not sure if it suits my needs. I did find a framework for client/server programming on Java, it's called Jboss netty and it's pretty much what i was looking for. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

JBoss netty: http://www.jboss.org/netty